# When I put LIKE% starts Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, html, mysqli

im creating a search bar, this bar if we put for example plants, i want to search all the things with the name plants, what is the problem, im working with image and with SQL Statement, and I have a problem.

I have the error `Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064` because I put `LIKE%`, the operator for search, and I have an error.
The Public function:

```html
public function viewbusq()
 {
  $busqueda=$_GET["buscar"];
  $SQLStatement = $this->DBConexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM productosima LIKE'%$busqueda%'");
  $SQLStatement->execute();
 

   
        while($img = $SQLStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    <div class="producto">
                <div class="name_producto"><?php print($img['id']); ?></div> 
    <div class="cajafoto">
                <div><img class="img_producto" src="<?php print($img['imagen']); ?>"/></div> 
    <a href="#"><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="See"></a>

          </div> 
         </div>
  <?php 

  }
 }
```

Page that make the search in the DB:

```html
<?php
$busqueda=$_GET["buscar"];
require("BSQparametros.php");

$conexion=mysqli_connect (DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

if(mysqli_connect_errno() ){
    exit();
}

mysqli_select_db($conexion,DB_DATABASE) or die ("No results");

mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");

$consulta="SELECT * FROM productosima WHERE imagen LIKE'%$busqueda%'";

$resultados=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    ?>
    <?php 


   
    include 'MOST.coneccion.php';
    if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
    $DBImagen->uploadImage($_FILES);
    }
    
   
    
    $DBImagen->viewbusq();
    
    ?> 
<?php 
    
}
mysqli_close($conexion);


?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Because your query string is missing "Where": Let update query string look like.

```
$SQLStatement = $this->DBConexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM productosima WHER filename LIKE'%$busqueda%'");
```